# Need to extract specific string in between 2 characters using Salesforce formula

Tags: formula, formula-field

I would like to extract specific data in the url and create a formula field.

[https://www.carsdirect.com/buildyourcar/models-guide/labor-day?makeName=honda&src=1000851&utm_content={creative}&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Honda+Make&utm_term=%2Bhonda+%2Blabor+%2Bday+-+Broad&lnk=AC:google|CP:Honda+Make|AG:Honda+Labor+Day+Deals+-+BM|KW:%2Bhonda+%2Blabor+%2Bday|MT:Broad|ADID:{creative}|MKWID:{ifsearch:s}{ifcontent:c}4b4zXZ2X_d{device}|N:{network}|P:{placement}|TID:{targetid}|LOC:{loc_physical_ms}|DM:{devicemodel}|FID:{feeditemid}|PGRID:{adgroupid}&intent=Make](https://www.carsdirect.com/buildyourcar/models-guide/labor-day?makeName=honda&src=1000851&utm_content=%7Bcreative%7D&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Honda+Make&utm_term=%2Bhonda+%2Blabor+%2Bday+-+Broad&lnk=AC:google%7CCP:Honda+Make%7CAG:Honda+Labor+Day+Deals+-+BM%7CKW:%2Bhonda+%2Blabor+%2Bday%7CMT:Broad%7CADID:%7Bcreative%7D%7CMKWID:%7Bifsearch:s%7D%7Bifcontent:c%7D4b4zXZ2X_d%7Bdevice%7D%7CN:%7Bnetwork%7D%7CP:%7Bplacement%7D%7CTID:%7Btargetid%7D%7CLOC:%7Bloc_physical_ms%7D%7CDM:%7Bdevicemodel%7D%7CFID:%7Bfeeditemid%7D%7CPGRID:%7Badgroupid%7D&intent=Make)

I would like to get the data for AC to a custom formula field, CP Value to another custom formula field, ADID value to another formula  field and MKWID to another field.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  We cannot implement your requirements or provide complete designs, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter in your own implementation process.  Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and where you are stuck.